# Update a single line

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I don't understand why this is not working.

```
db.UserConnected.find( {} )
```

returns

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ce262920cb02b4724dbdc0d"), "idUser" : null, "mode" : "Passager", "latitude" : 50, "longitude" : 60 }
```

So, as you can see, I've got an object in my UserConnected document.

He is inserted with the following peace of code where it's logged new user.
Now what I'm trying to do is update an user already connected...but this is not working and I don't know why.

```
    socket.on('new', function(information) {
        console.log(information._id);
        user = {};
        //user already connected
        if(information._id !== undefined){
            console.log("update user");
            user.id = information._id;

            user.idUser = information.idUser;
            user.mode = information.mode;
            user.latitude = information.latitude;
            user.longitude = information.longitude;

            //Update the user connected here if that user exists
            collection.updateOne({"_id" : information._id}, {$set:user} );
            socket.emit('user_modified', user);


        }else{
            console.log("new user");
            //nouvel user
            user.idUser = information.idUser;
            user.mode = information.mode;
            user.latitude = information.latitude;
            user.longitude = information.longitude;

            collection.insertOne(user);
            console.log(user);
            socket.emit('user_inserted', user);
        }
    });
```

I send the data like this if I'm not connected

```
var information = {"idProfile" : 1, "mode" : "Passager", "latitude": 50, "longitude" : 60 };
```

Like this if I'm connected

```
var information = { "_id" : "ObjectId('5ce262920cb02b4724dbdc0d')", "idProfile" : 1, "mode" : "Passager", "latitude": 500, "longitude" : 60 };
```

I might miss something really simple but can't find what.

EDIT: When I try with a query he can't find a match neither

```
db.UserConnected.updateOne( {"_id": "ObjectId('5ce262920cb02b4724dbdc0d')" }, {$set : {"longitude": 70}} )

{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 0, "modifiedCount" : 0 }
```

==========================================================

I can't answer the issue I don't know why....anyway here is the solution then:

Sending the data as a simple string in the client side `"5ce262920cb02b4724dbdc0d"`

And then using this as a filter

`{"_id" : ObjectID(information._id)}`

with 
`var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;`

Comment: This is wrong. `"_id": "ObjectId('5ce262920cb02b4724dbdc0d')"` it should be `"_id": ObjectId('5ce262920cb02b4724dbdc0d')`. The `ObjectId` is  a function imported from the library in your node driver and not a "string" as you are sending it.

Comment: In modern environments you would typically import as `const { ObjectId } = require('mongodb')`